# Running tests in parallel on the mobile app and web browser

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, npm, appium, webdriver-io

Help me guys. I need to run the e2e tests in parallel on mobile app and on the web browser, then make some changes on mobile app and check the changes on the web browser and vise versa several times. I plan to use webdriver.io + appium(as a service for webdriver.io).
But if exists other frameworks or tools for this, I can use them.

Case, for example:

1. Open the web page on the browser and add some text to input field(or attach the file).
2. Open the mobile native app on mobile emulator, synchronize the data(app functionality) and check entered text.
3. Enter text on mobile and save the changes. Push 'Synchronize' button(or wait 5 minutes).
4. Switch to the opened(step 1) web page and check the entered text(or picture).
5. Repeat steps 1-4 several times.

Comment: What have you tried so far? have you followed a tutorial on how to use Appium? Are you stuck on a specific step?

Comment: @ChukUltima, yes:
- I set capabilities for web and android device on **web.conf.js**
- Created the file with selectors for android.
- Created the file with functions (pageObject), imported the created selectors and added the capabilities: **browser.select('androidClient')**
And now I stuck on next point: how correctly to add the iOS device capabilities. In my case the same code should be used for tests web+iOS, as used for web+android.

Comment: How to use different files with selectors (iOS and android) for the same piece of code.
I mean something like this:
if (client == android ){
    const selector = require('.//aElements.js');
} else {
    const selector = require('./../iElements.js');}

Answer (score 0):

You can use wdio multi remote to achieve this. Your config should look like below and you can access the app with the appiumDriver.doSomething() and browser with chromeBrower.doSomething() in steps:

```
capabilities: {
      appiumDriver: {
         port: 4723,
         capabilities: {
            // maxInstances: 1,
            platformName: 'Android',
            deviceName: 'Pixel_4',
            app: join( process.cwd(), '<path to apk>' ),
            autoGrantPermissions: true,
            appWaitActivity: '*',
            fullContextList: true,
            webviewConnectTimeout: 10000,
         },
      },
      chromeBrowser: {
         port: 4444,
         capabilities: {
            browserName: 'chrome'
         },
      },
   },
```